# How to change Hibernate connection.url property from java code at application startup

Tags: java, database, hibernate, properties, hsqldb

hibernate.cfg.xml :

```
 <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:hsqldb:file:mycustomurl</property>
        <property name="connection.username">sa</property>
        <property name="connection.password"></property>
```

I have a custom installation folder for my application  where i want to locate my hsql database.Problem is that i initialize location in main class of my application each time on startup.**How can i change**

```
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:hsqldb:file:mycustomurl</property>
```

**mycustomurl** **from my main application** ?So i can work with user defined application directory?I woud also want to change  username/password property from main class.Where i will generate password from license file each time on startup.Is there a way to do it?I have tryed many ways bud methods/tutorials that i found were deprecated.I use latest version of hibernate/hsqldb .

Can i maybe generate hibernate.cfg.xml somewhere on hdd then (somehow) load it ?Whats the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried changing the configuration programmatically? (http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en-US/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-programmatic)

Comment: look for `Configuration` like `Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();` and then `configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url",myUrl);`

Comment: @nachokk Will i have to then remove my whole cfg.xml file or they can be combined with use of " Configuration "?

Comment: can be combined, do you have an `HibernateUtil`  ?

Comment: @nachokk Didnt get that far yet.I'm currently following this tutorial http://www.icesoft.org/wiki/display/ICE/Creating+Your+First+Hibernate-Enabled+Application This get me confused and i had to find answer for it ,so i hope it works :) Im new to hibernate.

Answer (score 3):

In your helper class you could put something like this

I copy from the [link](http://www.icesoft.org/wiki/display/ICE/Creating+Your+First+Hibernate-Enabled+Application) you provide

```
public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure()
                    .setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", "MY URL");
            ServiceRegistryBuilder serviceRegistryBuilder = new ServiceRegistryBuilder()
                    .applySettings(configuration.getProperties()); 
            return configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistryBuilder
                    .buildServiceRegistry());

        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

}
```

Comment: This is a similiar way that i tyed before bud ServiceRegistryBuilder is deprecated and that threw me off.Is this ok to use deprecated class?

Comment: @TomasBisciak what hibernate version are u using? i have hibernate4 and is not deprecated

Comment: 4.3.5 final its latest

Comment: @TomasBisciak i have 4.2.6 and is not deprecated there, may be i don't know there is another way to create then better :D

Comment: i decided to go hibernate-less .. and create my own framework-like way of doing things:) anyway thx for help

Comment: @TomasBisciak your own framework? Reinventing the wheel. You can achieve with this what you want, you can add more properties if you want `hibernate.connection.username`

Comment: Yhe i know its kinda overkill bud hej,wholepoint of  my project is just to get better and some skills so, hopefully i will succeed.I might look for some other solution or go back to hibernate if i will hit the wall.